# oh-my-zsh autocompletion when changing dir without cd

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I installed oh-my-zsh on my new machine. Ever since then, when I want to change directory without using `cd` and try to auto-complete the folder name with `TAB` oh-my-zsh outputs suggestions containing all possible commands. How to change this to auto-complete to folders and files only.

Screenshot with example:
[image: screenshot of terminal demonstrating issue]

What I want is, that pressing `TAB` results in auto-completion of the `flutter`-folder.